# Titanium - Android Emulator - INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android, google-maps, sdk, titanium

I've created an application in Titanium it runs on the iPhone Simulator but I can not get it working on the Android Emulator.

I think the issue is to do with Google maps, Java reports the class as not being found.

The emulator uses the target Google API (API Level 16) which includes the Google Maps API.

Is this the correct target for Titanium Apps with Google Maps, are there some other settings that are required?

For example in your Tiapp.xml

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

I'm using Windows 7 for the Android builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you installing specific parts of the Android SDK or the entire thing?  I can't find where I found this before, but make sure ALL components are installed for the target and see if that works for you.  This error is annoying that it doesn't exactly tell you WHY it isn't installing or which piece it is missing.